# Give contours from right to left in Opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I want to print center of contours with `"findContours"` function from right to left contours, in opencv c++. when i print centers, i see contours Not have particular order.
Is there a way to implement an order to contours in opencv c++?

Comment: Sort the centers of contours in the way you want and then print them.

Comment: @ZdaR, I want to know is possible that  work Automaticly with options of "findContours" function or other functions..??

Comment: @ZdaR, I am early in c++ and opencv. How can i Sort contours with their centers??

Comment: Store the center of contours in a std::vector and sort it.

Comment: @narges There are bound to be hundreds, if not thousands questions and answers here on sorting things in c++. Do some research, and then think of a way how to apply what you learn in your particular context. Try to implement your algorithm, test it, debug it, and when you're truly stuck, ask a specific question about the problem you're having, showing the relevant code, etc. The fact that you're new to a language or a library just means you need to excercise the above much more, in order to gain that experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
// Find all the contours
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(Image, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
sort(contours.begin(), contours.end(), Right_Left_contour_sorter());
```

and " `Right_Left_contour_sorter`" function is :

```
struct Right_Left_contour_sorter // 'less' for contours
{
    bool operator ()( const vector<Point>& a, const vector<Point> & b )
    {
        Rect ra(boundingRect(a));
        Rect rb(boundingRect(b));
        return (ra.x > rb.x);
    }
};
```