# Android RTL with Camera2

Tags: android, opencv, right-to-left, android-camera2

I am wondering why the camera preview is different when Camera2 API is used with RTL language. Specifically, I have two questions:

1. Are there any specific settings on the camera when RTL is used?
2. I'm using edge detection via OpenCV. Does OpenCV have any RTL functionality?

Comment: How is the camera preview different when using an RTL language?

Comment: @cristan: Yes that was my question too.. how camera frame can release different frames when RTL is enabled and disabled? Where camera1 is very much fine and problem is only with camera2 api

Comment: Which problem??? How it is different and what do you want to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch an atribute [`supportsRtl`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl) for right-to-left languages support in your application manifest file (*AndroidManifest.xml*):

```
    <application>
        ...
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        ...
    </application>
```

> If set to true and targetSdkVersion is set to 17 or higher, various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so your app can display RTL layouts. If set to false or if targetSdkVersion is set to 16 or lower, the RTL APIs will be ignored or will have no effect and your app will behave the same regardless of the layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice (your layouts will always be left-to-right).

So disabling this option will make camera preview look same as for right-to-left, but your app will not be able to use RTL layouts that RTL API provides.

What do you mean when talking about computer vision library and edge detection in context of right-to-left languages? Edge detection does not depend on text reading and writing orientation. If you just want to get the edges in right-to-left order, you can find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954947/give-contours-from-right-to-left-in-opencv-c) useful.

[This article](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2) may be helpful if you want to learn more about RTL support on Android and what you need to change to use RTL layouts.

If you want your application to support RTL but keep camera preview widget in ordinary left-to-right view, you can force it to stay left-to-right using `android:layoutDirection` attribute. Set it for this widget as

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

It will override the application `supportsRtl` attribute for this particular widget.

Comment: Thankyou so much for you help. I was talking about the camera. Can you help me in that also. Link you provided explains about the design part.

Comment: @PandiriDeepak Edited the question. Camera2 API itself seems to have no specific options for RTL. If this wont help, please be more specific about what you want to achieve as I still do not understand what is the problem and what is your desired outcome that differs from obtained result. Add code / screenshots / detailed description or anything else you are able to post here that might help to clarify the problem.